# IntelliJ not working - When I start my program it finishes before input

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I tried to install and run IntelliJ on a new laptop and I have this problem: When I write the program and try to start it it immediately ends with Process finished with exit code 0 without me even typing something as input.
Also these messages show up:

Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58043', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58043', transport: 'socket'

I have no idea whats the problem and I'll really apreciate if someone can help me fix it.

Comment: Please share the code of your program so that we can see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Exit code 0 means that whatever you ran, executed successfully without error. Is it possible that you have written a class with a main method, but that the main method does nothing? i.e. there is no body to your main method. That would give the behaviour you describe above.

Comment: Hello, as I said above it's a new laptop situation and I discovered that my keymap doesnt work, most of the shortcuts dont work at all in intellij. For example when i press ctrl + shift + f10 it doesn't run the program as usual so i run it from the button in the upper right corner. I figured the problem with my program finishing this way is beacause this way of running actually runs another code. So now the problem i need to fix is how to make my keymap work again. I'm sorry, my questions are probably very dumb but i am very new in the programming world and just now learning what's everything.

Comment: Go to Settings - Keymap: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html. It also looks like you mixed two unrelated questions into one: why your usual hotkeys don't work and why your program exits immediately. I also recommend reading SO's [How to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Among other useful advice, it says *see if anyone comments. If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your question to include it*.